# UE5; fatal error: CoreMinimal.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, unreal-5, visual-studio-code

I am leaning to use UE5 and am following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQgOqyYoHAs

However, when I try to compile a simple pawn class on vscode, I am given the error: "CoreMinimal.h: No such file or directory".

I have tried:

- refreshing vscode through UE5
- adding UE5's public folder to PATH
- Uninstalling and reinstalling both UE5 and vscode

I am out of ideas, I have tried every solution I could find on google.